# How do I figure out garbage collection counts on PS Old Gen through JMX?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am trying to get retrieve collection count on the Old generation remotely to another application through JMX. My initial approach was to examine MemoryPool and GarbageCollector objects. I see that under MemoryPool -> PS Old Gen -> MemoryManagerNames I have:

1. PS MarkSweep

Now, I could just look at GarbageCollector -> PS MarkSweep -> CollectionCount. However, PS Eden Space memory pool has the same algorithm registered:

1. PS MarkSweep
2. PS Scavenge

There must be a way of getting information specific to one pool. VisualGC has a way of knowing:

[image: visualgc]

Comment: There should be an object for the stats for the Old Gen as well. Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: I'm currently using JVisualVM to explore the MBeans. Eventually this will go into a monitoring system which will poll the collection count via JMX. As I already mentioned, there is an object called MemoryManagerNames, but the algorithm listed there appears in other memory pools as well so I can't look at the collection count for that algorithm.

Comment: When I have used code to get all the memory regions they have all been there. I suggest you try that.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple - garbage collection is always JVM wide (not memory pool specific). Though some algorithms (e.g. young collection - PS Scavenge) may process just one pool, while others (PS Mark Sweet) are processing whole heap (eden + old space + perm space).

So there is no specific count PS Mark Sweep for eden space, there is just total number of PS Mark Sweep was performed in JVM.

Number you are seeing in VisualConsole is the same a you see in GarbageCollector -> PS MarkSweep -> CollectionCount MBean.